# What does this shorthand mean?

Tags: notation, orchestra, instrumentation

I was reading an article on the Internet and saw this notation:

> 3*3*3*3* – 4331 – tmp+3 – hp – cel/pno – cds (14/12/10/8/6)

Then, searching on Google, I could see that this is a [shorthand for orchestra instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand_for_orchestra_instrumentation). But even reading this Wikipedia article, I could not understand all the parts of this statement.

What do all of these things mean? Mainly the final parts...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would recommend consulting the source where you found this. If it was a publishing company, they may have their own system of shorthand that will clarify this.

Otherwise, this all seems relatively standard:

- **3*3*3*3*** indicates the wind grouping with three performers each: three flutes, three oboes, three clarinets, three bassoons. The asterisks indicate that one of the players is playing another instrument of that family; one flute is also playing piccolo, one bassoon is also playing contrabassoon, etc. Contrast this with **3d**, where the third player is *doubling* on that instrument.
- **4331** indicates a standard brass grouping of four horns, three trumpets, three trombones, and a tuba.
- **tmp+3** indicates a timpanist and three other percussionists.
- **hp** indicates harp.
- **cel/pno** indicates a score for celesta/piano.
- **(14/12/10/8/6)** indicates the number of strings: 14 first violins, 12 second violins, 10 violas, 8 celli, and 6 double basses.

My only confusion is with the designation **cds** before the last entry. My guess is that this indication is in another language—perhaps French?—and this tells us that the following numbers pertain to "strings" (cordes in French).

Comment: I think specifically "cel/pno" means "celesta **or** piano".  It would be a little unusual to have both, though I imagine it's not unheard-of.

Comment: I don't agree about cel/pno.  I think it would normally be celesta **and** piano, but with one player taking both instruments (perfectly feasible if the instruments are never playing together and there is a little time to change seats).